# How to add dropdown while clicking on the Icon using react Js?

Tags: reactjs

I am using Modal for comments section which has an icon called dotsHorizontal icon. Please help me on putting the responsive dropdown, so that while clicking on dotsHorizontal icon it will display the Dropdowns listing Edit Message, Delete Message and so on which is responsive as well.

Below is how my code looks like.

```
import React, { useState }  from 'react'
import { StyledEditCommentsModal } from '.'
import { HeartIcon,ReplyIcon,DotsHorizontalIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'
import { CommentInput,Select } from '../../System'
const EditCommentsModal = props=> {
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
    const [imageURL, setImageURL] = useState(null)
    const [name, setName] = useState("Angel Queen")
    const [time, setTime] = useState("6h")
    const [likes,setLikes]=useState("75k")
  

    const handleImageUpload = (e) => {
      if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
        let img = e.target.files[0]
        setImage(img)
        setImageURL(URL.createObjectURL(img))
      }
    }

   if(!props.show){
       return null
   }
    return (
        <StyledEditCommentsModal>
      <div className="layerContainer">
          <div className="modal" onClick={props.onClose} >
              <div className="detailsGrid" onClick={e=>e.stopPropagation()}>
              <div className="modalHeader">
                  <div className="leftHeaderContainer">
                  <h4 className="modalTitle">Comments</h4>
                  </div>
           
              <div className="rightHeaderContainer">
              <h4 className="countComments">2</h4>
             
              </div>
              <span className="closeModalBtn" onClick={props.onClose}>X</span>
              </div>
               {/* First comment Description */}
              <div className="modalBody">
              <div className="avatarWrapper">
              <img className="img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2104252/pexels-photo-2104252.jpeg"/>
          
          </div>
          <div className="bodyContainer">
              <div className="topDetails">
              <div className="commentUsername"> {name}</div>
             <div className="hour">{time}</div>
             <div className="horizontalIcon"><DotsHorizontalIcon/>        
             </div>
         
              </div>
              <div className="commentDescription">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
                  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
              </div>
              <div className="commentFooter">
              <div className="likeIcon">
              <HeartIcon/>
              </div>
              <div className="numberOfLikes">{likes}</div>
              <div className="replyIcon"><ReplyIcon/></div>
              </div>
             </div>
              </div>

              {/* Second comment Description */}
              <div className="modalBody">
              <div className="avatarWrapper">
              <img className="img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2104252/pexels-photo-2104252.jpeg"/>
          
          </div>
          <div className="bodyContainer">
              <div className="topDetails">
              <div className="commentUsername"> {name}</div>
             <div className="hour">{time}</div>
             <div className="horizontalIcon"><DotsHorizontalIcon/></div>
              </div>
              <div className="commentDescription">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
                  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
              </div>
              <div className="commentFooter">
              <div className="likeIcon"> <HeartIcon/></div>
              <div className="numberOfLikes">{likes}</div>
              <div className="replyIcon"><ReplyIcon/></div>
              </div>
              
          
             </div>
             
              </div>
              <div className="modalFooter">
             <CommentInput  />
              </div>
              </div>
        </div> 
        <div className="backdrop" onClick={props.onClose} />
        </div>
        </StyledEditCommentsModal>
    )
}

export default EditCommentsModal
```

Comment: To show/hide dropdown based on click, you can use a state variable to manage the state of dropdown.

Comment: Hi, I am confused how to add a select option on the icon

Comment: You need 2 things, icon and select box. On clicking the icon, please change a state variable (boolean), and based on the value of the state variable, hide/show the select box with options

Answer (score 0):

You can add an internal state for conditionally displaying the dropdown.

```
const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false)
```

And change the state according to the button press,

```
 <div className="horizontalIcon"><DotsHorizontalIcon onClick={() => setDropdownOpen(prevState => !prevState)/></div>
```

And display the dropdownOpen inside the code as

```
{dropdownOpen && <div> //Code for dropdown </div>}
```